# Jekyll define fonts in config.yml

Tags: css, yaml, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to define font variables in my jekyll template's _config.yml so that I can use liquid in my css and change all type styles directy from config. Somehow it's not rendering, is this even possible?

This is what I have in my _config:

```
fonts:

 primary: Roboto Slab

 secondary: Helvetica
```

And css:

```
body {
  font-family: '{{ site.fonts.primary }}',{{ site.fonts.secondary }},Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide YAML front matter in order for Jekyll to process Liquid tags in the css file:

```
---
---
body {
  font-family: '{{ site.fonts.primary }}',{{ site.fonts.secondary }},Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

The `---` lines are the start and end of YAML front matter. You do not need to define anything in it.

Comment: Yes, indeed I had forgotten those but it doesn't work either. Should I create the font variables  inside the front matter in the css? how should the syntaxis be in this case?

Comment: *It doesn't work either* is not an appropriate problem description. Please elaborate how your CSS file looks like after being processed with Jekyll.

Comment: The css renders out with the place where the liquid object should be empty. p {font-family: '  ',"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;} The first two semicolons should have 'Karla' font inside. Other color tags I defined in config work just fine, only this one doesn't!

Comment: Ok, it finally works. My problem was that I had to quit and serve the site again every time I made  changes in config.yml, because they are not seen by --watch. Thank you for your time though!

Comment: How can I also change the title page font size? What parameter do you use in the same YAML front matter?

Comment: @Stryker Comment sections are not for additional questions; you can ask a new question giving all necessary information and linking to this if it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply declare these variables in your sass file ?

Comment: yes you could do that but in order to design a template that for example someone who doesn't know sass could implement it's very clean to let them just define the fonts they would like to use in config.yml. It's a simple solution!