# How can I change the default font for a Jekyll website

Tags: css, yaml, jekyll

I'm new to using Jekyll, css, etc, and I forked the [Jekyll now](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now) repo. Is there a way I can change, or add, default fonts to the entire jekyll website? It looks like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955342/jekyll-define-fonts-in-config-yml) may have some answers, but I don't really understand it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit the file [`style.scss`](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now/blob/v1.2.0/_sass/_variables.scss) located at the root of the jekyll instance, you can change the font from this:

```
body {
  ...
  font: 18px/1.4 $helvetica;
}
```

to this:

```
body {
      font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

or whatever font you want.

If you want to make it better, use variables, add them to [`_sass/_variables.css`](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now/blob/v1.2.0/_sass/_variables.scss)

```
$times: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
```

and then change in [`style.scss`](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now/blob/v1.2.0/_sass/_variables.scss):

```
body {
    font: 18px/1.4 $times;
}
```

Comment: If you are using the default Jekyll theme "Minima", please edit the file `minima.scss` instead of the `style.scss`. To change the default font definition you need to reset the value of `$base-font-family` variable, e.g.: `$base-font-family: "PT Serif", serif;` You will also need to remove the `!default;` suffix at the end of this setting.

Comment: @mabalenk is this comment still accurate or does Minima now use `style.scss` also? [Minima source code reference](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/tree/master/assets/css)

Answer (score 2):

check this
[Font change Jekyll](http://remotemanifesto.com/jekyll-specific-css-and-web-fonts-for-latest-posts-on-homepage/)

The answer you mention telling is to edit your _config.yml file by adding the font names. i prefer add your font in sass file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a font asset to your project instead of using web-hosted fonts, you can import the font file into the project's assets folder.  For the theme I'm using (`minimal-mistakes`), the correct assets folder is located in `ROOT/docs/assets/`