# Changing a Font in an Jekyll Theme

Tags: css, sass, webfonts, jekyll-theme

I have been experimenting with Jekyll a little bit the last days. I guess I understand the basics about it. I tested around 4 Templates and got them to run and understand the structures of a jekyll page. It isnt much magic tbh.

Today I came to the point where I wanted to change the font of my Template. I am using the [Type on Strap](https://github.com/sylhare/Type-on-Strap) Teamplate at the moment and you can see my repo I build on git pages [Right here.](https://github.com/manilevian/jekylltest2)

I checked out [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551672/how-can-i-change-the-default-font-for-a-jekyll-website). Which helped me to identify the _variables.scss file in the _sass/base folder. Also the thread goes on, saying that the whole file might be controlled through a scss file, mostly called like the theme. There we go, I found the Type-on-Strap in the _sass folder.

Now my question is: Do i have to edit the _variables.scss like I did below, and If so, where to I put the ttf files or how do i link correctly to the webfont ? Or will I leave the _variables files as it is and only have to edit the type-on-strap.scss file ? and if so again, what do I have to change ?

The _variable.scss file:

```
// Typography
$font-family-main: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
$font-family-headings: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
$font-family-logo: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
$font-size: 1.25em;
```

So I dont want to use Sans Pro anymore. I would like to use [Barlow Semi Condensed](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Barlow+Semi+Condensed) as ther main font, and Barlow Semi Condensed Medium for the headings and logo. Would I change the code to this?:

```
$font-family-main: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
$font-family-headings: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
$font-family-logo: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
```

Summary: I only want to know, what do I have to edit how to get Barlow font to replace the sans pro one on my template I am using.

Hope people arent too mad about me making another post about this. I crawler through some of the answers and this is day two in trying. Kind of getting exhausted :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hey thanks for using the theme.
I see two solutions for your problem

1. If you are not familiar with sass, there are often the possibility to import directly the css of your font in the [head.html](https://github.com/sylhare/Type-on-Strap/blob/master/_includes/head.html). Try looking for an "embedded" version.

For this font you could just add this line in your header, and modify the `_variable.scss` as you did for it to work.

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

2. if you want to manually add your font with sass/scss, there's no magic, you will need to:

   - download the fonts and put them in /fonts mind the naming, you'll need it.
   - Check out how it was done for "*Source Sans Pro*" in [_sass/external/_source-sans-pro.scss](https://github.com/sylhare/Type-on-Strap/blob/master/_sass/external/_source-sans-pro.scss). Add a new file like `BarlowSemiCondensed.scss` with all the right information.
   - Create a `@font-face` for the font you'll be using.(Usually what you get when you [download](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Barlow+Semi+Condensed?selection.family=Barlow) the font, just copy those files).
   - Don't forget to import any new .scss file in [type-on-strap.scss](https://github.com/sylhare/Type-on-Strap/blob/master/_sass/type-on-strap.scss)